# Configure debian ddclient with dyndns noip.com

Tags: debian, dyndns

I'm having trouble to configure debian jessie as noip.com updater. My config looks like this:

```
# Configuration file for ddclient generated by debconf
#
# /etc/ddclient.conf

use=web
web=checkip.dyndns.com
web-skip='Current IP Address: '

protocol=dyndns2
server=dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update
login=myusername
password='mypass'
myhost.noip.me
```

everything seems to be fine but if I ping myhost.noip.me the ip address is not updated. By checking

```
ddclient -daemon=0 -debug -verbose -noquiet 2 /etc/ddclient.conf
```

I get the following reply:

```
.conf
=== opt ====
opt{cache}                           : <undefined>
opt{cmd}                             : <undefined>
opt{cmd-skip}                        : <undefined>
opt{daemon}                          : 0
opt{debug}                           : 1
opt{exec}                            : <undefined>
opt{facility}                        : <undefined>
opt{file}                            : <undefined>
opt{force}                           : <undefined>
opt{foreground}                      : <undefined>
opt{fw}                              : <undefined>
opt{fw-login}                        : <undefined>
opt{fw-password}                     : <undefined>
opt{fw-skip}                         : <undefined>
opt{geturl}                          : <undefined>
opt{help}                            : <undefined>
opt{host}                            : <undefined>
opt{if}                              : <undefined>
opt{if-skip}                         : <undefined>
opt{ip}                              : <undefined>
opt{login}                           : <undefined>
opt{mail}                            : <undefined>
opt{mail-failure}                    : <undefined>
opt{max-interval}                    : 2592000
opt{min-error-interval}              : 300
opt{min-interval}                    : 30
opt{options}                         : <undefined>
opt{password}                        : <undefined>
opt{pid}                             : <undefined>
opt{postscript}                      : <undefined>
opt{priority}                        : <undefined>
opt{protocol}                        : <undefined>
opt{proxy}                           : <undefined>
opt{query}                           : <undefined>
opt{quiet}                           : 0
opt{retry}                           : <undefined>
opt{server}                          : <undefined>
opt{ssl}                             : <undefined>
opt{syslog}                          : <undefined>
opt{test}                            : <undefined>
opt{timeout}                         : <undefined>
opt{use}                             : <undefined>
opt{verbose}                         : 1
opt{web}                             : <undefined>
opt{web-skip}                        : <undefined>
=== globals ====
globals{daemon}                      : 60
globals{debug}                       : 1
globals{login}                       : myusername
globals{password}                    : mypass
globals{protocol}                    : dyndns2
globals{quiet}                       : 0
globals{server}                      : dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update
globals{use}                         : web
globals{verbose}                     : 1
globals{web}                         : checkip.dyndns.com
globals{web-skip}                    : Current IP Address:
=== config ====
config{myhost.noip.me}{atime}          : 0
config{myhost.noip.me}{backupmx}       : 0
config{myhost.noip.me}{cacheable}      : ARRAY(0x1770c50)
config{myhost.noip.me}{cmd}            : <undefined>
config{myhost.noip.me}{cmd-skip}       :
config{myhost.noip.me}{custom}         : 0
config{myhost.noip.me}{fw}             :
config{myhost.noip.me}{fw-login}       : <undefined>
config{myhost.noip.me}{fw-password}    :
config{myhost.noip.me}{fw-skip}        :
config{myhost.noip.me}{host}           : myhost.noip.me
config{myhost.noip.me}{if}             : ppp0
config{myhost.noip.me}{if-skip}        :
config{myhost.noip.me}{ip}             : <undefined>
config{myhost.noip.me}{login}          : myusername
config{myhost.noip.me}{max-interval}   : 2592000
config{myhost.noip.me}{min-error-interval} : 300
config{myhost.noip.me}{min-interval}   : 30
config{myhost.noip.me}{mtime}          : 0
config{myhost.noip.me}{mx}             :
config{myhost.noip.me}{password}       : mypass
config{myhost.noip.me}{protocol}       : dyndns2
config{myhost.noip.me}{script}         : /nic/update
config{myhost.noip.me}{server}         : dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update
config{myhost.noip.me}{static}         : 0
config{myhost.noip.me}{status}         :
config{myhost.noip.me}{use}            : web
config{myhost.noip.me}{warned-min-error-interval} : 0
config{myhost.noip.me}{warned-min-interval} : 0
config{myhost.noip.me}{web}            : checkip.dyndns.com
config{myhost.noip.me}{web-skip}       : Current IP Address:
config{myhost.noip.me}{wildcard}       : 0
config{myhost.noip.me}{wtime}          : 30
=== cache ====
cache{myhost.noip.me}{atime}           : 0
cache{myhost.noip.me}{backupmx}        : 0
cache{myhost.noip.me}{custom}          : 0
cache{myhost.noip.me}{host}            : myhost.noip.me
cache{myhost.noip.me}{ip}              : 12.34.56.78
cache{myhost.noip.me}{mtime}           : 1437992275
cache{myhost.noip.me}{mx}              :
cache{myhost.noip.me}{script}          : /nic/update
cache{myhost.noip.me}{static}          : 0
cache{myhost.noip.me}{status}          :
cache{myhost.noip.me}{warned-min-error-interval} : 0
cache{myhost.noip.me}{warned-min-interval} : 0
cache{myhost.noip.me}{wildcard}        : 0
cache{myhost.noip.me}{wtime}           : 30
DEBUG:    proxy  =
DEBUG:    url    = checkip.dyndns.com
DEBUG:    server = checkip.dyndns.com
CONNECT:  checkip.dyndns.com
CONNECTED:  using HTTP
SENDING:  GET / HTTP/1.0
SENDING:   Host: checkip.dyndns.com
SENDING:   User-Agent: ddclient/3.8.2
SENDING:   Connection: close
SENDING:
RECEIVE:  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
RECEIVE:  Content-Type: text/html
RECEIVE:  Server: DynDNS-CheckIP/1.0
RECEIVE:  Connection: close
RECEIVE:  Cache-Control: no-cache
RECEIVE:  Pragma: no-cache
RECEIVE:  Content-Length: 103
RECEIVE:
RECEIVE:  <html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>Current IP Address: 12.34.56.78</body></html>
DEBUG:    get_ip: using web, checkip.dyndns.com reports 12.34.56.78
SUCCESS:  myhost.noip.me: skipped: IP address was already set to 12.34.56.78.
```

I tooks like my current (artificial) IP "12.34.56.78" has been set properly. Now if I ping (my artificial host) myhost.noip.me I get a different IP.

Any suggestion what I need to change to get ddclient working with noip.com?

Answer (score 1):

The trace you show shows that `ddclient` polled `checkip.dyndns.com` for the IP of your machine, saw that the IP had not changed and consequently **decided to skip contacting `dynupdate.no-ip.com` to change the IP**. If it had contacted `dynupdate.no-ip.com`, you would see a line like this in your trace

```
CONNECT:  dynupdate.no-ip.com
```

and it would be followed by a bunch of `SENDING` and `RECEIVE` lines.

I found that if you want to force `ddclient` to perform the entire operation, you should stop any currently running daemon with `sudo service ddclient stop` and remove its cache file with `sudo rm /var/cache/ddclient/ddclient.cache`. Then any subsequent run will necessarily perform all the checks.

Also, your configuration file is wrong. You should not have `/nic/update` in the `server` setting, as this is part of the `protocol` setting. (Using `dyndns2` as the protocol implies that `/nic/update` is appended.) For reference, my current configuration is:

```
use=cmd
cmd='dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com'

protocol=dyndns2
ssl=yes
server=dynupdate.no-ip.com
login=<YOUR LOGIN>
password=<YOUR PASSWORD>
<YOUR HOST>
```

I use the `dig` command to get my public IP rather than contact a server through HTTP.

Comment: removing the cache was a big help for me. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
protocol=noip
```

I'm using noip but with the protocol noip, like it was inside of the --help flag, look at this help to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing wrong with your config is the server update address. It should be:

```
# Configuration file for ddclient generated by debconf
#
# /etc/ddclient.conf

use=web
web=checkip.dyndns.com
web-skip='Current IP Address: '

protocol=dyndns2
server=dynupdate.no-ip.com
login=myusername
password='mypass'
myhost.noip.me
```

You can test the configuration by executing:

```
sudo ddclient -verbose -foreground
```

And you should see the router part (extracting the IP addres using the 'web' provider), then the authentication with no-ip and the IP address being updated:

```
ONNECT:  checkip.dyndns.com
CONNECTED:  using HTTP
SENDING:  GET / HTTP/1.0
SENDING:   Host: checkip.dyndns.com
SENDING:   User-Agent: ddclient/3.8.3
SENDING:   Connection: close
SENDING:   
RECEIVE:  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
RECEIVE:  Content-Type: text/html
RECEIVE:  Server: DynDNS-CheckIP/1.0.1
RECEIVE:  Connection: close
RECEIVE:  Cache-Control: no-cache
RECEIVE:  Pragma: no-cache
RECEIVE:  Content-Length: 106
RECEIVE:  
RECEIVE:  <html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>Current IP Address: X.X.X.X</body></html>
INFO:     setting IP address to X.X.X.X for myhost.noip.me
UPDATE:   updating myhost.noip.me
CONNECT:  dynupdate.no-ip.com
CONNECTED:  using HTTP
SENDING:  GET /nic/update?system=dyndns&hostname=myhost.noip.me&myip=X.X.X.X HTTP/1.0
SENDING:   Host: dynupdate.no-ip.com
SENDING:   Authorization: Basic bHBlbmFwQGdtYWlsLmNvbToyNjg3OGxhcA==
SENDING:   User-Agent: ddclient/3.8.3
SENDING:   Connection: close
SENDING:   
RECEIVE:  HTTP/1.0 200 OK
RECEIVE:  server: envoy
RECEIVE:  content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
RECEIVE:  cache-control: no-cache
RECEIVE:  date: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 18:48:25 GMT
RECEIVE:  connection: close
RECEIVE:  
RECEIVE:  good X.X.X.X
SUCCESS:  updating myhost.noip.me: good: IP address set to X.X.X.X
```

Answer (score -1):

```
protocol=dyndns2
use=web, if=eth0
server=dynupdate.no-ip.com
login=username@email.com
password='mysuperpassword'
myhost.no-ip.org
```

You have "if=ppp0". Do you use a 'dial' connection? Mine has "if=eth0" because the dsl ppp is on modem/router.

```
Your ping test is on the same network, or you try on a different (outside) computer? Could be a local DNS issue.
```